# MySQL Replication: struggling with replicate-rewrite-db to change the database name

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have my master database with the one table in it, products (will have more later, this is just dev).

OS: CentOS 6.4

I have set it up as the master for replication using this:

In /etc/my.cnf:

```
server-id = 1
binlog-do-db=product_database
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
log-error = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.err
master-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
relay-log-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-log.info
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
```

On the master I created the user with this command:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'hcp_slave'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';
```

Then on the slave:

```
server-id = 2
master-host=HOST_IP_ADDRESS
master-connect-retry=60
master-user=hcp_slave
master-password=PASSWORD
replicate-do-db=product_database
#The below line is what causes issues
replicate-rewrite-db=product_database->product_database2
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
log-error = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.err
master-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
relay-log-info-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-log.info
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
```

Before I added the "replicate-rewrite-db" line (and with it removed) the replication works perfectly between the servers with the same database name. However, I need it to go into a database with a different name, for testing purposes, "product_database2."

From everything I have read in the mysql manual and on a few random forums (plus stackoverflow) I think I am using the replicate command properly, but clearly, I am not, so I would greatly appreciate a little help in figuring out where my issue lies, or if I am trying to go about this the entirely wrong way!

For those curious, what I am actually trying to do, in case I have an XY problem going on here:

I am trying to create a master database to feed products to a handful of websites instead of having to update them all manually. I figured the best way to do this would be to create 1 master database and have all the sites configured as slaves to automatically pull products from it.

Edit:

I tried commenting out the line 'replicate-do-db' in the slave configuration file, and at least now it is giving some indication of knowing that product_database2 exists, but it is in the form of an error:

```
Last_Error: Error 'Error on rename of './product_database/asdf.frm' to     './product_database2/asdf.frm' (Errcode: 2)' on query. Default database: 'product_database2'. Query: 'RENAME TABLE `product_database`.`asdf`
```

Comment: What do your logs tell you?

Comment: My /var/log/mysqld doesn't have any new entries added. My /var/lib/mysql doesn't have an error log created in like I would expect if something wasn't working.

Comment: I changed a line in the configuration file (chronicled above) and was able to elicit an actual error:  Last_Error: Error 'Error on rename of './product_database/asdf.frm' to './product_database2/asdf.frm' (Errcode: 2)' on query. Default database: 'product_database2'. Query: 'RENAME TABLE `product_database`.`asdf`

Comment: Since error 2 means the file doesn't exist, then at a guess the *slave config* (only) needs to be amended to `replicate-do-db=product_database2`

Answer (score 2):

On the slave side you need to set

```
replicate-do-db=product_database2
```

because you have rewritten db name like `product_database->product_database2`.

Answer (score 0):

From [refman](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db):

> Only statements involving tables are affected (not statements such as
>   CREATE DATABASE, DROP DATABASE, and ALTER DATABASE), **and only if
>   *from_name* is the default database on the master**.

So try this. Use the config you have above, but try adding a USE right before the query you run on master.

```
USE product_database;
INSERT INTO product_database (c1,c2) VALUES (1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem regarding database naming. My solution:

In the my.cnf file:

```
replicate-rewrite-db="product_database->product_database2"
replicate-do-db="product_database2"
```